# Find top features by Id(Contains Multiple documents with same Id) from DTM

Tags: r, text-mining, tm, term-document-matrix

I am using package tm.

I have a dataframe with 2 columns, the first column is ID and the seocnd column contains text. The dataframe looks as follows.

```
Id       Text
13456    Hi, Good morning
13457    How are you?
13456    May I know who I am speaking to?
13456    Hi, Good evening
```

I have used the tm package and built dtm and extracted the top 5 words for each document and it looks like:

```
Id       Term1 Term2 Term3   Term4 Term5
13456    Hi    Good  morning term4 term5
13457    How   are   you     term4 term5
13456    I     Know  may     who   to
13456    Hi    Good  Evening term4 term5
```

But the required output is:

```
Id      Term1 Term2 Term3 Term4   Term5
13456   Hi    Good  I     morning evening
13457   How   are   you   term4   term5
```

I could not find any previous questions posted on this.
Thanks in Advance.

Comment: Could you explicitely give the function you used (to have your dtm), to be able to try ?

Answer (score 0):

The problem you are facing stems from the fact that each line of your data is treated as individual document. Hence, you need to `aggregate` your data by ìd` before feeding it into the process of generating a dtm.

The following show and example of how to use `aggregate` in base R. If you have a huge number of documents this can be done more efficiently, e.g., by using the package `data.table`, which you might have a look at. However, to keep it simple, I use base R. (I have used own exemplary data, for the next time, please use `dput` or provide the code that generates your data to make it easier for others to read your example data.)

```
df <- data.frame(id = c(1, 1, 2) , text = c("text1.", "text2.", "text3."))
# id  text
# 1  1 text1.
# 2  1 text2.
# 3  2 text3.
df <- aggregate(df$text, by = list(df$id), FUN = function(x) paste(x, collapse = " "))
# Group.1            x
# 1       1 text1. text2.
# 2       2        text3.
colnames(df) <- c("id", "text")
```